# Select last record in table

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

How can i retrieve the last record from database using LINQ method?

```
   PayrollRun test2 = (from R in database.PayrollRun
           select R).LastOrDefault();
        d = test2.PayrollRunEndDate;
```

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'TradelineHR.Models.PayrollRun LastOrDefaultPayrollRun' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Is there any property or column can represent the order? how did you know which row is last record?

Comment: var test2 = database.PayrollRun.LastOrDefault(); should work. Does any other command (like FirstOrDefault) work? If not, there must be something wrong with the definition of the DBSet PayrollRun.

Comment: Databases have no notion of first or last in the data.  That is determined by you in your SQL, so it is not clear what you are asking (or why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention field, by which you want to use as ordering criteria.

Let's assume it is `PayrollRun.PayrollRunEndDate`

I think most intuitive and readable way to get LastOrDefault is to combine `.OrderByDescending()` and `.FirstOrDefault()`.

```
PayrollRun test2 = (from R in database.PayrollRun
           select R).OrderByDescending(r=>r.PayrollRunEndDate).FirstOrDefault();
d = test2.PayrollRunEndDate;
```

Comment: this will return first record in table while i need to return the last record

Comment: Check there is OrderByDescending before FirstOrDefault? Still wrong?

Comment: thx it works when i mentioned ID field with  OrderByDescending before FirstOrDefault